# Days of USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, dbms-scheduler, dbms-job

I would like to know if it is possible to know the number of days that Oracle keeps the data in the table `USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` and also if it is possible to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is depends from parameter of job_class , but if parameter is not set default value is 30 days (in oracle 11.2)

```
select job_class_name,log_history from dba_SCHEDULER_job_classes where job_class_name ='DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS';
```

to change the parameter.

```
 BEGIN
       DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute (NAME           => 'SYS.DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
                                     ATTRIBUTE      => 'log_history',
                                     VALUE          => 300 -- <-- in days
                                    );
    END;
```